# Wireless Doesn't Connect To The Internet

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Belkin N150 wireless router. If I connect a windows 7 laptop to the wireless network it accesses the internet no worries.

Another laptop running vista can connect to the wireless network, but doesn't get internet access.

What I did is disabled the security on the wireless network, and the vista laptop can connect after that.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some network cards can't handle certain security features. I have one that can not do TKIP. So, if you were using WPA2 try WPA and see if that makes a difference. Or as much as people say don't, try WEP. If one of the others works you know that your card just can't handle one of the options.

Comment: I will check that out again, but I think from memory (I tried a lot of things) that WEP, and WPA, and all different combinations of TKIP and AES didn't work.

Comment: Also the given question, are the drivers up to date/software.

Comment: Yeah perhaps not. It is not my laptop, so it is hard to say really. I will have to have a closer look.